# Position of a Substring in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

How I can get the position/Index of a substring within an `NSString`?

I am finding the location in the following way.

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchKeyword];
NSLog (@"match found at index:%u", range.location);
```

This returns `index:2147483647`  when `searchKeyword` is a substring within `string`.

How i can get the index value like `20` or `5` like that?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`2147483647` is the same thing as `NSNotFound`, which means the string you searched for (`searchKeyword`) wasn't found.

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchKeyword];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string was not found");
} else {
    NSLog(@"position %lu", (unsigned long)range.location);
}
```

Comment: thanks -@Kevin Ballard for help. do you help me that how i can select a substring on the bases of that range.    e.g. `And, of course, it must be asked:is it proper to transact with the Turks for the most reassured of Greek possessions when **Greece* is under Turkish invasion and subjugation?`.     here i found the location of Greece now i want to select a `substring` one or two words before and after of that Greece Words. like `when Greece is Under Turkish`.   can you help Please!

Comment: @ShaheenRehman: You probably want to use the `-enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` API. This can give you individual words.

Comment: -@Kevin Ballard can you give me code example of `-enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` API.

Answer (score 10):

```
NSString *searchKeyword = @"your string";

NSRange rangeOfYourString = [string rangeOfString:searchKeyword];

if(rangeOfYourString.location == NSNotFound)
{
     // error condition — the text searchKeyword wasn't in 'string'
}
else{
     NSLog(@"range position %lu", rangeOfYourString.location);
}

NSString *subString = [string substringToIndex:rangeOfYourString.location];
```

may this will help you....

Comment: thanks -@Kevin Ballard for help.   do you help me that how i can select a substring on the bases of that range. e.g.   `And, of course, it must be asked:is it proper to transact with the Turks for the most reassured of Greek possessions when **Greece* is under Turkish invasion and subjugation?.`   here i found the location of Greece now i want to select a `substring` one or two words before and after of that Greece Words.   like `when Greece is Under Turkish`. can you help Please!

Comment: you can use it.... 

[string substringToIndex:rangeOfYourString.location];

I am editing in the code... 
may this will help you

Comment: thanks -@Abhishek it work for me `[string substringFromIndex:range.location];`